# Tensorflow serving: "No assets to save/writes" when exporting models

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

Recently I am trying to deploy deep learning services using tensorflow serving. But I got the following infos when exporting my model:

```
  INFO:tensorflow: No assets to save
  INFO:tensorflow: No assets to write
  INFO:tensorflow: SavedModel written to: b'./models/1/saved_model.pb'
```

I don't really understand what happening here. What does "No assets to save/write" mean? Is everthing goes well?
   btw，by running the official example [Serving a tensorflow model](https://www.tensorflow.org/serving/serving_basic), I got the same infos.

Answer (score 27):

Assets mean any external files that are needed for you model. Common examples are vocabularies and embedding matrices. If your model does not have any external dependencies, these messages are expected. Note that they are logged at "INFO" level.

Comment: Thank you! That's really helpful.
btw, can all "INFO" level logs be treated as "Everything goes well"?

Comment: You are welcome. INFO logs generally mean that something important for the user to know has happened and there is no reason for tensorflow to think that something is wrong. It might still be wrong - say you actually wanted to include assets and forgot - but generally you can ignore them.