# Deploying TensorFlow Checkpoint to Google Cloud Platform

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, google-cloud-platform

I have trained a TensorFlow model and saved a checkpoint, and would like to deploy it to Google Cloud Platform.  In the model deployment [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/deploying-models) it says that you need to create a SavedModel.  It seems that [others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42216208/should-tensorflow-users-prefer-savedmodel-over-checkpoint-or-graphdef) also use checkpoints instead of SavedModel.

Given that I have already spent time training this model and only have checkpoints instead of a SavedModel, is there a method I can use to deploy the model still or will I need to retrain?

Answer (score 1):

A checkpoint maps variable names to tensor values. This, as is, is not enough for higher-level systems to use your model. On the other hand, a [SavedModel](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/saved_model/README.md) is complete and airtight. As is made clear in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42216208/should-tensorflow-users-prefer-savedmodel-over-checkpoint-or-graphdef) you link to in your post, a SavedModel provides all the info needed for serving TensorFlow models: a set of MetaGraphs, a checkpoint compatible with these Graphs and all necessary asset files. If you look at it this way, it makes sense that you need to export your model to a SavedModel in order to deploy it to ML Engine. Now, this does not imply that you need to retrain. What you need to do instead is to [wrap one of your checkpoints into a SavedModel](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/saved_model#performing_the_export).