# TensorFlow: Saving py_func to .pb file

Tags: python, tensorflow

I try to build a tensorflow model - where i use the tf.py_func to create a part of the code in ordinary python code. The problem is that when I save the model to a .pb file, the .pb file itself is very small and does not include the py_func:0 tensor. When I try to load and run the model from the .pb file I get this error: get ValueError: callback pyfunc_0 is not found.

It works when I dont save and load as a .pb file

Is anyone able ton help. This is super important to me and have given me a couple of sleepless nights.

```
model_version = "465555564"
tensorboard = TensorBoard(log_dir='./logs', histogram_freq = 0, write_graph = True, write_images = False)

sess = tf.Session()
K.set_session(sess)
K.set_learning_phase(0)

def my_func(x):
    some_function

input = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
y = tf.py_func(my_func, [input], tf.float32)

prediction_signature = tf.saved_model.signature_def_utils.predict_signature_def({"inputs": input}, {"prediction": y})
builder = saved_model_builder.SavedModelBuilder('./'+model_version)
legacy_init_op = tf.group(tf.tables_initializer(), name='legacy_init_op')
builder.add_meta_graph_and_variables(
      sess, [tag_constants.SERVING],
      signature_def_map={
           signature_constants.DEFAULT_SERVING_SIGNATURE_DEF_KEY:prediction_signature,
      },
      legacy_init_op=legacy_init_op)

builder.save()
```

Comment: This is one of it's limitations. "The body of the function (i.e. func) will not be serialized in a GraphDef"

Comment: Is there anyway I can get around this??

Comment: What I want to do is to load a .pickle file containing a "Random Forrest Model". That model I want to run inside Tensorflow

Comment: You can try using autograph, https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/autograph

Comment: There is an implementation of random forests in TensorFlow, see [TensorForest](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/r1.13/tensorflow/contrib/tensor_forest). Note this is currently under `tf.contrib`, which [will disappear in TensorFlow 2.x](https://github.com/tensorflow/community/blob/master/rfcs/20180907-contrib-sunset.md). See the RFC [TensorForest Estimator](https://github.com/tensorflow/community/blob/master/rfcs/20180626-tensor-forest.md) for the accepted plans for `tensor_forest`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There **is** a way to save TF models with `tf.py_func`, but you have to do it **without** using a `SavedModel`.

TF has 2 levels of model saving: checkpoints and `SavedModels`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43531616/6078821) for more details, but to quote it here:

> - A checkpoint contains the value of (some of the) variables in a TensorFlow model. It is created by a [`Saver`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/Saver). To use a checkpoint, you need to have a compatible TensorFlow `Graph`, whose `Variable`s have the same names as the `Variable`s in the checkpoint.
> - [`SavedModel`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/saved_model) is much more comprehensive: It contains a set of `Graph`s ([`MetaGraphs`](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/+/r0.10/tensorflow/g3doc/how_tos/meta_graph/index.md), in fact, saving collections and such), as well as a checkpoint which is supposed to be compatible with these `Graph`s, and any asset files that are needed to run the model (e.g. Vocabulary files). For each `MetaGraph` it contains, it also stores a set of signatures. Signatures define (named) input and output tensors.

The `tf.py_func` op *cannot* be saved with a `SavedModel` (noted on [this page in the docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/py_func)), which is what you tried to do here. There is a good reason for this. `SavedModel`s are supposed to be totally independent from the original code, able to be loaded in any other language that can deserialize it. This allows the models to be loaded by things like [ML Engine](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/), which is probably written in C++ or something like that. The problem is that it cannot serialize arbitrary Python code, so `py_func` is a no-go.

You *can* work around this by using checkpoints, as long as you are okay with staying in Python. You will not get the independence that `SavedModel`s provide. You can save a checkpoint after training with a `tf.train.Saver`, and then in a new `Session`, re-build the whole graph and load it with that `Saver`. There is even a way to use that code in ML Engine, which used to be exclusively for `SavedModel`s. You can use [custom prediction routines](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tensorflow/custom-prediction-routines) to side-step the need for a `SavedModel`.

More info on saving/restoring models in [the docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model).