# Continue training on SavedModel or load checkpoint from SavedModel

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving, tensorflow-estimator

In tensorflow 1.14, it's obvious that `tf.compat.v1.train.init_from_checkpoint` can load `ckpt` to continue training (or to warm start). However, I couldn't find any corresponding approaches in [SavedModel](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.14/api_docs/python/tf/saved_model), and [tf.estimator.WarmStartSetting](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.14/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/WarmStartSettings) only supports `ckpt` as well. It's weird for me, because [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42216208/should-tensorflow-users-prefer-savedmodel-over-checkpoint-or-graphdef) mentioned that there should be a checkpoint stored in `SavedModel`. Does anyone know:

1. How to load checkpoint in SavedModel? or
2. How to warm start training on SavedModel?

Comment: If you are having model code with you, it is better to do saving and restoring using checkpoints.``` https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/checkpoint``` . It is even compatible with tf1.0 to load old checkpoints saved using ```saver.save()```

Comment: Thank you @SarathRNair. I know that checkpoints work. However, I'd like to deploy my model on tf-serving, which requires SavedModel format. That's why I'd like to know how to warm start from SavedModel, because I don't want to save and load the model twice (checkpoint and SavedModel).

Comment: Have you got a solution to this?

Comment: Hi @SarathRNair, unfortunately, I haven't found a solution. I also asked this question in TF repo https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/33162 I hope they will have this new feature or someone could have other simple solutions.

Answer (score 0):

In order to load SavedModel to continue training, you can use tf.saved_model.loader.load like follows:

```
graph = tf.Graph()
with tf.Session(graph=graph) as sess:
  tf.saved_model.loader.load(sess, [tag_constants.SERVING], saved_model_location)
```

In order to feed new input data, you can get the input tensor names like follows:

```
signature_def = meta_graph_def.signature_def[tf.saved_model.signature_constants.DEFAULT_SERVING_SIGNATURE_DEF_KEY]
inputs = [v.name for v in signature_def.inputs.values()]
input_tensors = [node.split(":")[0] for node in inputs]
```

then you can make some kinds of `feed_dict` to feed new inputs to the input tensors. Getting output tensors can be done similarly to the method I outlined above.